# Using redis-connect but sessions are being dropped on node.js server restart

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using redis as the session store in an express based node.js project. The sessions work fine generally but when I restart the application server I find that all my sessions are lost (ie. all users are redirected to the homepage).

I can see the session keys are still accessible within redis by using the redis admin tools.

Any ideas?

My server setup looks like the following...

```
var redisSessionStore = require('connect-redis')(express);
global.sessionStore = new redisSessionStore({prefix:"sess:"});
app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({ secret: sessionSecret, store: global.sessionStore, key: global.sessionCookieName, cookie: { secure: true, httpOnly: true, domain: "." + global.canonical, expires: false} }));
})
app.configure('development', function () { app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true })); });
app.configure('production', function () { app.use(express.errorHandler()); });
```

Comment: You're not regenerating `sessionSecret` at server startup?

Comment: Yes I was. Thanks robertklep.

What is doubly annoying was that I went looking for such a thing yesterday before posting and obviously glassed over it.

Answer (score 1):

Answered by @robertklep

The problem was being caused by sessionSecret was changing on each restart.